# Scratching with mouse to reveal a symbol

Tags: textures

How can I make the minigame where you move a mouse around a rectangular grid and the symbol gets more or less "apparent" as shown below? (I can do mouse things, don't know how to approach making the symbol scatter to bits)

[image]
[image]

Comment: How much do you know about fragment shaders?

Comment: What's your technology stack?

Comment: We have "hard to find" [questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=Scratch+is%3Aquestion) about this, you might want to take a look at those.

Comment: @Vaillancourt searching for ["scratch card" questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22scratch+card%22+is%3Aquestion) narrows the results significantly.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this would be to have 4 textures:

- a pre-scratched texture
- a post-scratched texture
- an alpha mask which determines which of the latter textures are visible
- a "brush" or scratch texture(s) which will be used to paint onto the alpha mask.

When the user clicks you would stencil the brush texture onto the alpha mask at the mouse position. Depending on the particularities of your environment and implementation, you might have to do some converting between mouse-space and texture-space. This "painting" operation which would reveal the scratched texture could happen on the cpu or gpu, depending on how much you care about performance and how comfortable you are with shaders.